# Assign the value to variable in 2 different sub and call the variable based on the value in perl

Tags: perl

I need help in calling the value from the variable from 2 different subroutines and assigning the value based on input.

For example: I have 3 different subroutines named `sub xxx`, `sub yyy` and `sub execute`. Two subroutines named as `xxx` and `yyy` will be defined as the input of the value. The `execute` sub will take the input based on the value supplied while executing `main.pl`:

```perl
sub xxx 
{
    my $input = "repository_1";
}

sub yyy
{
    my $input = "repository_2";
}

sub execute
{
    $output=$input;
    print "This is the Repository connected : $output";
}
```

When I run the `main.pl` script, it will call either sub `xxx` or sub `yyy` based on the input, and it will execute the output if repository_1 or repository_2.

For example, if I run `$main.pl xxx`, I am able to connect to sub `xxx` and skip sub `yyy`. But I want the sub `execute` to take the input from sub `xxx` as `repository_1`. And so that I can display the `$output` of the repository like this:

```
$ main.pl xxx
This is the Repository connected : repository_1
```

Comment: Thanks to format/indent your code properly when asking human help. Kind of respect

Comment: You want a hash table, not a bunch of subs.

Comment: This is bad design. You don't want to call subroutine names based on input, otherwise  a user could pass any subroutine name to your program which could lead to undesired effects. Any reason not to use a hash (xxx => 'repository_1', etc) ?

Comment: If those subs provide more behavior than just assigning a value you can still use a hash to dispatch to different subroutines based on user input.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, my subs are performing more actions that assigning the value to the variable $input. Like, the sub first call the configuration file from some location, then call the variables including this $input, and performs some action. And, i wanted the same input to be passed onto sub execute. So that, sub execute will run based on what sub (xxx or yyy) it calls. 
if sub xxx calls, sub execute will display "This is the Repository connected : repository_1". 
if sub yyy calls, sub execute will display "This is the Repository connected : repository_2".

Comment: I am not good in perl script and trying myself. I am not sure if below syntax is correct. Is this the right way to assign the repository_1 or repository_2 to hash.

sub xxx 
{
#reads the configuration file
$repository{'input'} = 'repository_1';
#performs some other action
}
sub execute
{
$output=$repository{'input'};
print "This is the Repository connected : $output";
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical use for a [dispatch table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispatch_table)<sup>†</sup>, so that we can call the right function based on input (or perhaps other key words but without having to hardcode it)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $input = shift // die "Need input\n";

sub xx
{
    #say "In xx(), my input: @_";
    # ... work out output:
    my $output = "repository_1";
    return $output;
}

sub yy
{
    #say "In yy(), my input: @_";
    # ...
    my $output = "repository_2";
    return $output;
}

sub execute
{
    my @output = @_;
    print "This is the Repository connected : @output\n";
}

my %dispatch = ( xx => \&xx, yy => \&yy );

# Is there a function to dispatch to for the given input?
my $call_sub = $dispatch{$input} // die "Input ($input) not supported";

execute( $call_sub->() );
```

Can add more sophisticated handling for unsupported input.

Prints

```
> perl dispatch_ex.pl yy
This is the Repository connected : repository_2
```

---

<sup>†</sup>  In Perl this is normally implemented as a hash which has *code references* for values and their keys are suitable names that allow us to retrieve them as needed.

A code reference is either a reference to a named function, as used here, or it is an *anonymous subroutine*

```
my $code_reference = \&name_of_some_function;
# or
my $code_reference = sub { ... };
```

This is then a scalar like any other, that can be passed around, stored in arrays or hashes (as a value; having it as a key -- even though technically allowed -- wouldn't make sense).

Note that it is the function *name*, no parenthesis. Then it is called (dereferenced) as

```
$code_reference->( @arguments );
```

If it is called without any arguments we still need (empty) parenthesis.

Documentation: a tutorial [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut) and a reference [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref), and [perlsub](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am afraid this would not work for me, because there are so many subroutines in my perl module and all subroutines performs too many operations. I just wanted to call this sub xxx from some other subroutine and take the input alone.

Comment: @PrakashSomasundaram"_I am afraid this would not work for me_" -- OK, as you say (I could only work with what is in the question), and thank you for the comment. But I don't understand -- This only organizes more conveniently how to call those functions.  Make them return whatever you want (I typed just some demo code, which btw prints exactly what your question asks), and call them from wherever you want.  All that this suggests is to put functions into a hash so you can directly call the right one based on input, without having to hardcode it.

Comment: @PrakashSomasundaram Perhaps a clarification is in order: `$call_sub = $dispatch{$input}` selects a function to call (`xx`? `yy`? ...), based on `$input`, and then `execute( $call_sub->() );`  calls it (`$call_sub->()` calls the sub which reference is in `$call_sub` variable). You can put function arguments into the parenthesis. Then that function's return is passed to `execute()`, which then runs.  So whatever your functions return is passed to `execute()`

Comment: @PrakashSomasundaram The question says: "_When I run the main.pl script, it will call either sub xxx or sub yyy based on the input,..._" -- that is precisely what this code does (and then it does the second part of that sentence).  If that's actually not quite what you need then perhaps post another, more specific question, with more detail.  While it's possible to sometimes read between the lines and imagine what the poster needs, in principle we can only answer questions as they are posed :)

Comment: Yea you are right. I think i need to understand the functionality of execute and try to implement in the code. Thank you for the detailed explanation. I am overwhelmed :)

Comment: @PrakashSomasundaram  OK -- let me know if more/better explanation is needed.  While _code references_ seem (and are) a bit advanced, in practice it is very easy to use them (and once you start you'll like them).  Try it, if possible in your set up; it's easy and should improve things a lot.

Comment: I am still a beginner in Perl and trying to understand the usage of sub and hash elements. I will try to understand the purpose and implement in my coding, Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 4):

The issue with your code is the `my $input` lines create variables that are local to the `xxx` and `yyy` functions. That means `$input` will not have any value when you use it in the `execute` function.

Running your code with `use strict` and `use warnings` will show the problem

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub xxx 
{
    my $input = "repository_1";
}

sub yyy
{
    my $input = "repository_2";
}

sub execute
{
    my $output = $input;
    print "This is the Repository connected : $output\n";
}
```

outputs

```
Global symbol "$input" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $input"?) at try.pl line 16.
```

A very quick fix is to declare `$input` at a global scope and use `@ARGV` to trigger the calling of `xxx` or `yyy`.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input;

sub xxx 
{
    $input = "repository_1";
}

sub yyy
{
    $input = "repository_2";
}

sub execute
{
    my $output = $input;
    print "This is the Repository connected : $output\n";
}

xxx() if $ARGV[0] eq 'xxx';
yyy() if $ARGV[0] eq 'yyy';

execute();
```

```
$ perl main.pl xxx
This is the Repository connected : repository_1
```

**NOTE**: the use of `@ARGV` in the code above is purely to create a self-contained script that allows `xxx` or `yyy` to be executed on demand. The real code should not only this technique if the control of `xxx` and `yyy` needs to be controlled from the command line.

Recommend that all you Perl code includes the `use strict` and `use warnings`. It catches issues like this for for you for free.

Without knowing more about your script, it is difficult to make any other recommendations.

Comment: I am having difficulty in using this approach because sub xxx contains lots of other actions, and so if i can use xxx() in ARGV, then it is not working. i think i need to use ARGV in some other way except "xxx() if $ARGV[0] eq 'xxx';" Also, i failed to mention that my main.pl is calling branch.pm. and this branch.pm contains these 2 subs xxx and yyy. There are 10 subroutines inside branch.pm and all subroutines (including xxx and yyy) performs lot of operations. I only wanted to declare "$input=repository_1" in sub xxx and "$input=repository_2" in sub yyy and call $input in execute sub.

Comment: The use of `@ARGV` in my sample code was only intended to illustrate how `execute` can be influenced by a call to `xxx` or `yyy`. It was not intended to be used in real code. Comment updated.

Comment: Suggest you either update the question or create a new one that has more detail on your problem.  Ideally you need a self contained script that we can run that illustrates the core problem.

Comment: Ah ok I understand. Maybe I will try to incorporate the similar setup. But sincere thanks for your response though.